# How To Know if a paypal transaction is succeed?

Tags: api, paypal

I am creating a website where user can buy digital stuff. Its not downloadable material or something like, just a sensitive data.

I used paypal payment button and integrated it to my website. I tested it using paypal sandbox. So, i would like to perform a certain action once the user purchase the item and roll back to the site. So please tell me how it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

For any post-transaction processing you want to do you should use [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and administrative functions, like automatically fulfilling orders and providing customers with order status.

For PHP PayPal provides [a basic IPN script to get you started](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php).  Alternatively, you could take a look at [this IPN template solution](https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template) I put together many years ago.  It has an installer that sets up a MySQL database for you, and then it automatically saves all of the IPN into the database and emails you notifications.  You could start with that and then easily customize it to suit your needs.

Comment: I am completely a noob. Please help me out creating a paypal IPN listener

Comment: Are you working with PHP?  Working with WordPress or any particular framework?